# Add 'title' attribute to an element (using event)

Tags: jquery

This is my code in HTML:

```
<img id="test" src="https://blah">
```

This is in my jQuery and it works:

```
$( document ).on( 'mouseover', 'img', function(e) {
}
```

How can I add attribute to this 'img' element? I want this:

```
<img id="test" src="https://blah" title='test'>
```

I tried:

```
e.attr('title', 'test');
e.prop('title', 'test');
this.attr('title', 'test');
$(this).attr('title', 'test');
this.prop...
```

so on and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) method:

```
$('img').hover(function() {
    $(this).attr('title', 'test');
});
```

In this case, `$(this)` represents the image that has been hovered over.

You can also do:

```
$('img').hover(function(e) {
    $(e.currentTarget).attr('title', 'foo');
});
```

In this case, `$(e.currentTarget)` represents the image that has been hovered over.

Comment: I would, but I need that `e`. I am using it to grab data about this `img`.

Comment: `e.target.setAttribute('title', 'test');` helped me, which I took from your answer. But I left the `$( document ).on( 'mouseover', 'img', function(e) {`